# Jmeter engine & threads query

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, ruby-jmeter

What is Jmeter Engine ? Is it same as Jmeter instance we have on our machine ? .. I want to understand difference between Jmeter instance and Jmeter engine , also how can we setup multiple engines on same machine so that I can put more load on application through difference engines..

I read somewhere, where one of the Jmeter expert mentioned that we can use 300 vusers at a given time , is that correct ? I dont see any limit on vusers I use in Jmeter thread group.. I can enter any number.. please clarify

Comment: Instead of asking for particular terminology details - could you please define your problem? Like, "I want to create a certain load, but my JMeter on my machine(s) can't handle it", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jmeter engine and jmeter instance is related terminology. One Jmeter engine can generate one instance of jmeter.

Set-up for configuring two Jmeter engines on same machine:

Pre-requisite:
Jmeter should be installed on both machines

Steps:

1.Set-up master machine -

Add machine2 ip (slave machine ip) in jmeter.properties file of machine1 (master machine)[image]

2.Set-up slave machine - Run Jmeter-server.bat from machine2. This will make machine2 as slave

3.Launch Jmeter from machine1. You will be able to see slave engine ip in remote start
[image]

4.You can use remote start option, this will run Jmeter test cases from both the machines